# Unable to browse repository after setting visual SVN Server

Tags: svn, windows-7, windows-services, visualsvn-server

I have setup VisualSVN Server 2.1.7 on my windows 7 x64 system. I have used all default options :

- Installed path : C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server
- Repositories path : D:\Repositories
- Server name, port : testsrvr, 8443 (use secure connection = checked)
- Using "subversion authentication". 
  I have created a user and a test repository. Given "Read/Write" access to that repository for that user.

When I try to browse the repositories, IE shows "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". I tried these but nothing has helped yet.

- Turned off firewall
- Set the directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server" security rights to "full control" for most groups including "Network service" group.
- Set the directory "D:\Repositories" security rights to "full control" for most groups including "Network service" group.
- Tried switching between secure and non-secure connection option in visual svn server manager.
- Tried different with port numbers. Including 443 (with https) and 80 (http). Also tried giving random ports with/without https.

After these operations i always turned service off and then turned back on.

No success yet. Any more suggestions i can try ?

I tried to see using nmap if the service was running on port 8443. I'm not sure what nmap should be showing in ideal case but in my case it shows 
Port : 8443/tcp  State: unknown SERVICE: https-alt

Comment: is `testsrvr` pointing to the server you are using? Are you 100% sure?

Comment: How do I confirm that ? In visualsvn server properties the server name is "testsrvr" and "server port" is 8443. And then i right click the repositories and click browse which opens up the error page in IE with url https://testsrvr:8443/svn/

Comment: try the IP address of the server (or `localhost` if it's on the same machine)

Comment: @Pekka That amazing...it works with ip. Thanks !It asks for my user authentication. I, not clear though why it does not work with testsrvr:8443/svn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, it works if you use the IP address instead.

To address it through the name, you need to set up your server to listen to the `testsvr` server name. Specifying the name in the SVN server is not enough.

If it's just for one computer, you can fake server names in the [`hosts` file](https://superuser.com/questions/178292/why-is-127-0-0-1-localhost-needed-in-hosts-file). If it's for more machines, you will need to set up [DNS](https://serverfault.com/questions/187058/setup-a-local-dns-server).